# navigation controller Back button is hide why?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am using navigation controller in my project and when I navigate from my table view which is there in root view and if I want to come back to home screen it must show back button by default but it does not show me. Where is my mistake, is it related IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the back button in the root view controller for whatever nav view you push onto the stack.  You do this with code, not in interface builder